# xmrig.exe is not recognized as a internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: gpu-mining

Hello I am trying to set up an xmr rig on my laptop. When I run the the start.cmd it runs without issue, but I get low hashrate issue. So I am trying to run as admin but then I get the following error:

"xmrig.exe is not recognized as a internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably not, but if running from a command line try ./xmrig.exe.  Been a while since I was on a Windows box, but hopefully they removed ./ (local directory) from the PATH.  Its a minor security issue to have ./ in the PATH.

Answer (score 1):

You may edit `start.cmd` and add as the very first line:

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

This will change directory from the current one ("C:\Windows\System32") to the one the batch file is.

You may otherwise edit the `PATH` global variable of Windows to include the folder where you stored the `xmrig.exe` executable.